# Increasing wcf max received message quota

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm trying to invoke my service method but I'm getting

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline
>   or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the
>   proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for
>   more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring
>   to default configuration, or refreshing the service.
>
> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been
>   exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize
>   property on the appropriate binding element.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ThrowMaxReceivedMessageSizeExceeded()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.GetMessageBuffer()  ...
>   Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)  ....
>
> Inner Exception: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages
>   (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the
>   MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

**I tried to put max Int64 value as a value for maxReceivedMessageSize element but I still getting same error!**

```
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
             <binding name="myClientBinding" receiveTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="9223372036854775807"/>     
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings> 
    <client>      
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/myService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="myClientBinding" contract="MyServiceInterface" 
              name="myClient" />
    </client>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, it looks like the server is the one complaining about the maxReceivedMessageSize. Update the service-side binding to the max size you want.

I would pick a smaller number that reflects your maximum reasonable limit, unless you really want to support a request size of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 bytes.